# Calculating mutual information over distance

Tags: markov-process, mutual-information

I'm having trouble reproducing this figure measuring mutual information as a function of the distance between symbols in text/music/genome/etc:
[image: mutual information distance]
from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06737v2.pdf

Specifically, I'm trying to reproduce the `Markov process` red line by generating a Markov sequence, then calculating mutual information as a function of distance.

If I take some transition matrix:

[image: transition matrix]

And generate a sequence (e.g. `array([8, 7, 7, 9, 0, 4, 2, ...`)

How do I create my two distributions? For example:

```
dist_a = sequence[distance:]
dist_b = sequence[:-distance]
```

By making distributions this way, on the Shakespeare plays dataset I get a graph that looks like this:
[image: markov shakespeare]

where MI Markov is generated from a Markov process, and MI random is the a random permutation of the original texts (all at the level of characters). This clearly does not fit with the above graph, so I assume there is another way of sampling these two distributions? MI here is calculated using sklearn.metrics

Comment: Love this question and the Tegmark paper referenced! One thing about the graph that strikes me is the difference in the shape of the Markov process versus the others. The former looks lognormal while the others appear much more heavy tailed.

Answer (score 1):

As your distances get larger, the length of `dist_b` decreases and you begin undersampling the joint distribution for your MI computation. This can result in biasing your mutual information estimate high.

See the corrections the authors used in Section D.

If you don't want to code up their MI estimator yourself, you might have better luck with the corrections in the `pyentropy` package rather than the (apparently biased) sklearn implementation.

Comment: ![slightly different](http://i.imgur.com/aZld9p5.png) results using pyentropy...